# breadth first traversal directed vs undirected graph

Tags: breadth-first-search, directed-graph

how does bfs on directed and undirected graph differ in implementation.

i found the following pseudocode on web. i am ok with undirected graph. but can't figure out how to implement it for directed graph.

```
 frontier = new Queue()
  mark root visited (set root.distance = 0)
  frontier.push(root)
  while frontier not empty {
     Vertex v = frontier.pop()
    for each successor v' of v {
    if v' unvisited {
        frontier.push(v')
        mark v' visited (v'.distance = v.distance + 1)
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's just the same.

Comment: ahh got that already.. thanks for the response

Comment: well..Thanks to that guy who up-voted my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation in pseudocode is the same, except that the notion of `successor` would mean *neighbor* for an undirected graph but *child* (or similar) for a directed graph.

Comment: addNode(a, b);
        if(dir == "no")
        {
            addNode(b, a);
        }

Comment: is the above setup correct?? if its directed one way access is provided. else 2 way access is provided